# Can you tell me why this web scraper isn't able to log in correctly?

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I'm trying to make a web scraper to get some information from the site Colloquy.com, on which I have an account. I am having trouble getting my scraper to log in to the site though. I'm using Python 2.7 with BeautifulSoup and Requests.

[Here is a screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyFNE.png)

[and here is a screenshot of the relevant HTML for the login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Gah.png)

I've tried several variations of this code, including adding the authorization key to the log-in info. However, no matter what I've tried, I always get the "un-logged-in version" of the site when I get the HTML.

I have a suspicion that this has something to do with the site's use of Javascript for the login (it uses a pop up box instead of a separate login page). However, I don't know enough about Javascript to handle this properly, and I haven't been able to find any sort of guide that's illuminating on this particular issue.

So hopefully someone can tell me what is wrong with my code/process or where I can find out how to deal with logins using Javascript.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you post the result of `result.cookies` ?

Comment: result.cookies just gives me    <RequestsCookieJar[]>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of attempting to scrape the login page where the javascript is, it appears they `post` the information to `https://colloquy.com/app/account/login`, so you could do something like the following to try and login.

```
import requests
resp = requests.post("https://colloquy.com/app/account/login", data={"email":"some.email@address.com","password":"Password"})
```

You could then use the `resp.cookies` to scrape the pages that you are wanting to get to.

```
cookies = resp.cookies
r = requests.get("https://colloquy.com/some-page", cookies=cookies)
# Get html etc
```

**Edit:** 
Usually in the case of a `login` page there will be a post action behind the scenes that will send the required information to login. Usually `username` and `password` etc. This can usually be found on Chrome using the `Developer Tools` or Firefox with [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) or [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/). In order to get where it will post the information I bring up the tools and will then complete the login prompt. Within the Network tab (Chrome--may vary for Firefox/Firebug) it will usually show a request to some page (usually login or something similar) after you have completed the login prompt/page and submitted your information. Clicking on this action will allow you to see some of the information for this request including the `Request Url` and `Request Method`. There will also be an area which will show the `Form Data` posted to the `Request Url`. You should then be able to use this information to make a similar `POST` to the `Request Url` with the `Form Data`.

**Note:** There are cases where the web developer may attempt to block certain [User-agents](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) in order to keep automated scripts and/or bots away, but you can usually just change the `user-agent` to a normal agent to bypass this restriction.

```
requests.post(url, headers={"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"})
```

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thanks so much for the clear, helpful response.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you found where they post the login info (for future reference)? I'm still not seeing that anywhere.

Comment: @adaaaam Added some of the information to my answer for you. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again :)